# Losgstah configuration issue

Tags: logstash-configuration

I begin with logstash and ElasticSearch and I would like to index .pdf or .doc file type in ElasticSearch via logstash.
I configured logstash using the codec multiline to get my file in a single message in ElasticSearch. Below is my configuration file:

```
input {
  file {
     path =>  "D:/BaseCV/*"
     codec => multiline {
     # Grok pattern names are valid! :)
     pattern => ""
     what => "previous"
        }
     }
}
output {
   stdout {
     codec =>  "rubydebug" 
           }
elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost"
    index => "cvindex"
    document_type => "file"
     }
  }
```

At the start of  logstash the first file I add, I recovered in ElasticSearch in one message, but the following are spread over several messages. I wish I had the correspondence : 1 file = 1 message.
Is this possible ? What should I change my setup to solve the problem ?
Thank you for your feedback.